# how to transform object with list of properties to array when Array.prototype.slice.call does not work?

Tags: javascript

This is working for list:

```
> Array.prototype.slice.call([1,2,3])
> [1, 2, 3]
```

How to create list from this type of data `{1: "1", 2: "2", 3: "3"}` ? Are there other methods than iterating object with `for` ?

the `Array.prototype.slice.call()` is not working here and gives `[]`

This came from `data = Object {0: Object, 1: Object, 2: Object, total : '29'}` and then i `delete data['total']` and need to access to `slice`, `pop` and other methods of `Array`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the keys and map the values.

```js
var o = {1: "1", 2: "2", 3: "3"},
    a = Object.keys(o).map(function (k) {
        return o[k];
    });

console.log(a);
console.log(Array.prototype.slice.call({1: "1", 2: "2", 3: "3", length:5}));
```

The question arised, why `Array.prototype.slice.call` does not work. Basically because a length property is missing.

Only properties, which can be used as indices are used.

```js
var o1 = {1: "1", 2: "2", 3: "3"},
    o2 = {1: "1", 2: "2", 3: "3", length: 5},
    o3 = {1: "1", 2: "2", 3: "3", abc: 42, length: 5},
    o4 = {0: "0", 1: "1", 2: "2", 3: "3"};

o4.length=Object.keys(o4).length;
console.log(Array.prototype.slice.call(o1));
console.log(Array.prototype.slice.call(o2));
console.log(Array.prototype.slice.call(o3));
console.log(Array.prototype.slice.call(o4));
```

**Note:** Dynamic length of `properties-in-object` could be assigned using `Object.keys(OBJECT)`. The cause of getting `undefined` in console is *missing property at index `0`*

Comment: *Are there other methods than iterating object with for ?* Yes.

Comment: I am not arguing! Just asking for my reference ;)

Comment: Thank you Nina this look like exactly what I am looking for ! This came from `data = Object {0: Object, 1: Object, 2: Object, total : '29'}` and then i `delete data['total']` and need to access to `slice`, `pop` and other methods of `Array` , so this should help

Comment: @NinaScholz, I was about to post an answer about this ;) You might want to write a bit about __`0`__ index as well(cause of getting `undefined` as there is no value at index `0`)...+1

Comment: you can add it, if you like

Answer (score 1):

```
var list = [];
for (item in obj) {
    list.push(obj[item]);
}

//use list.push(parseInt(obj[item])) for number array
```

You can also do the following if you want it straight

```
Object.values(obj);
```

Comment: thanks, but there are no other options except iterating with for ?

Comment: See the updated one. iterating is best if you want to perform some other operations. But if its just the property values from object that you want, then second one is the way to do